# Unexpected Jetty Timeout

Tags: spring, jetty, apache-camel

I'm getting a timeout exception well before the set connection timeout.  Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on?

Any input would be great!

```
15 Jan 2013 10:44:40,944 [                   Thread-4622] WorkerThread                   INFO  [1538387622377815-4640]- - About to call server with connectionTimeoutMS=30000

15 Jan 2013 10:45:02,003 [                   Thread-4622] WorkerThread                   ERROR [1538387622377815-4640]-run():Connection timed out:java.net.ConnectException
```

I've recorded netstat, gc, and number of open files while the test has run and haven't noticed anything dramatic.

**Env**

- Java 1.6
- Jetty running Spring/Camel routes (camel 2.10)
- Client is muti-threaded (sending concurrent batch requests to the jetty component)

**File Descriptors:**

- ulimit -Hn 100000
- ulimit -Sn 100000

**Open Files**

- Bash script running cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr in 1 sec intervals:
- Before test begins:
  5664    0       200000
- Worst Case:
  6720    0   200000
- Both client and server are running on localhost.
- Client connection timeout set to 30 sec.

**How The Client Works**

Client creates batch of concurrent threads (rnd between 1-1000) and calls the jetty component then waits (rnd between 1-30 sec) before calling again.
This repeats up to 5 minutes.

Server: Experimented with using the default timeout and setting connectTimeout to a big number such as 60000 ms with the same result.

**On the server running**

- jetty-7.6.1.v20120215
- Camel 2.10.1
- Spring 3.0.7

spring/camel route:

```
<route id="startQueue_route" trace="false">
  <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9311" />
  <to uri="bean:LDAPBean" />
</route>

<bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent"/>
```

Comment: For assistance in formatting your question correctly, hit the big fat orange question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue but tweaking some of the tcp settings, hopefully this helps someone else.

I'm stepping back now and replacing the updated camel jars back to 2.10.0 to make sure the fix is simply a tcp env issue (timing out well before the set limit).

1) I updated camel and jetty to the latest/greatest for java 1.6, but still had the same 
random timeout issue.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  670388 Jan 16 18:23 spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  556747 Jan 16 18:24 spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  383621 Jan 16 18:25 spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   53082 Jan 16 18:26 spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  169749 Jan 16 18:27 spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   88733 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-servlets-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   97228 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-servlet-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  338985 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   89854 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-security-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   24596 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-jmx-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   87621 Jan 17 11:30 jetty-client-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  311747 Jan 17 11:30 commons-httpclient-3.1_1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  228640 Jan 17 11:30 camel-spring-2.10.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   52852 Jan 17 11:30 camel-jetty-2.10.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   66945 Jan 17 11:30 camel-http-2.10.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana 2218113 Jan 17 11:30 camel-core-2.10.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  280529 Jan 17 11:33 jetty-util-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   94481 Jan 17 11:34 jetty-http-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  231922 Jan 17 11:36 org.springframework.transaction-    3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  321190 Jan 17 11:37 org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  103293 Jan 17 11:39 jetty-io-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana  200387 Jan 17 11:45 servlet-api-3.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 dana dana   21138 Jan 17 11:52 jetty-continuation-8.1.8.v20121106.jar
```

2) Tweaked the tcp settings: (This seems to fix the timeout issue)

```
ulimit -n 124000

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries="1000000"
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries="1000000"
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=200000
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=5

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65000"
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time="30"

##-- disable ipv6.
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6="1"
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6="1"
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6="1"
```